# Combination Lock assignment in Java

Tags: java

I have an assignment where there is a combination lock box that has a 4-letter word as the combination, and a player has to try to guess the combination by guessing the word one letter at a time. For each round, a clue should be outputted to show how close a person's guess is to the actual word. If the letter in the guess is also in the same position in the combination lock, then the matching letter is outputted. If the letter is in the word but not in the same position, a `+` is outputted, and when the letter is not present in the word at all, an `*` is outputted. All of those characters are added to a single string to show the result.

I've tried to code all of this in Java, but it returns an incorrect result with a `null` before it. Can someone help me fix these issues?

```
public class CombinationLock
{
    private String lock;
    private String guess;
    private String guessLetter1;
    private String guessLetter2;
    private String guessLetter3;
    private String guessLetter4;
    private String lockLetter1;
    private String lockLetter2;
    private String lockLetter3;
    private String lockLetter4;
    private String modifiedGuess;
    private char combinationLetter;
    private char guessLetter;

    public CombinationLock(String newLock)
    {
        lock = newLock;
    }

    public String getClue(String newGuess)
    {
        guess = newGuess;
        for(int i = 0; i < lock.length(); i++)
        {
            combinationLetter = lock.charAt(i);
            guessLetter = guess.charAt(i);

            if(i == 0)
            {
                lockLetter1 += combinationLetter;
                guessLetter1 += guessLetter;
            }
            else if(i == 1)
            {
                lockLetter2 += combinationLetter;
                guessLetter2 += guessLetter;                
            }
            else if(i == 2)
            {
                lockLetter3 += combinationLetter;
                guessLetter3 += guessLetter;                
            }
            else if(i == 3)
            {
                lockLetter4 += combinationLetter;
                guessLetter4 += guessLetter;                
            }           

            if(combinationLetter == guessLetter)
            {
                modifiedGuess += combinationLetter;
            }
            else if(guessLetter1 == lockLetter1 || guessLetter1 == lockLetter2 || guessLetter1 == lockLetter3 || guessLetter1 == lockLetter4)
            {
                modifiedGuess += '+';
            }
            else if(guessLetter2 == lockLetter1 || guessLetter2 == lockLetter2 || guessLetter2 == lockLetter3 || guessLetter2 == lockLetter4)
            {
                modifiedGuess += '+';
            }
            else if(guessLetter3 == lockLetter1 || guessLetter3 == lockLetter2 || guessLetter3 == lockLetter3 || guessLetter3 == lockLetter4)
            {
                modifiedGuess += '+';
            }
            else if(guessLetter4 == lockLetter1 || guessLetter4 == lockLetter2 || guessLetter4 == lockLetter3 || guessLetter4 == lockLetter4)
            {
                modifiedGuess += '+';
            }
            else
            {
                modifiedGuess += '*';
            }
        }
        return modifiedGuess;
    }
}
```

```
public class MyProgram extends ConsoleProgram
{
    public void run()
    {
        CombinationLock c1 = new CombinationLock("bird");
        System.out.println(c1.getClue("barn"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise your modifiedGuess variable, i.e.

```
    public CombinationLock(String newLock)
    {
        lock = newLock;
        modifiedGuess = "";
    }
```

Alternatively, you can look into StringUtils.difference function which may give you a similar result (if allowed for the assignment).

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#difference(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)